# How to use the get induvidual values from a dictionary via key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I'm making a program in which you pair letters and symbols together to break a code, I'm using a dictionary to store all the pairs. I'm trying to make a system in where you can unpair symbols by accessing the dictionary and selecting a key (which is the symbol currently) and find find its value which can then be replaced back into the program using `.replace()`

The problem is I can't find a suitable way to allow the user to select individual keys from the dictionary and put the value into a variable which can then be used to undo the pairing. I have tried using the `.get()` function but I can't figure out how you could make a user select an individual key. Is there a specific function or can it be done with `.get()`

Here is my code:

```
if del_question == "2":
    print("These are your letter and symbol pairings")
    print(dictionary)
    if dict.get(dictionary):
        print(letter)
else:
    print('not found')

del_letter = input("Please input the symbol you wish to unpair: ")
if del_letter in words:
    del_symbol = dict.get(dictionary)
    words = words.replace(del_symbol, del_letter)
    del dictionary[del_letter]
    print(words)
else:
    print(del_symbol, "was not found")
```

and this is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "S:\Computer Scince\Controlled Assessment\Codebreaker.py", line 86, in <module>
print(del_symbol, "was not found")
NameError: name 'del_symbol' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Burhan's answer is probably the best way to do what you want to do. However, it doesn't explain your error message, and doesn't explain what is wrong with your current code.

Your error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "S:\Computer Scince\Controlled Assessment\Codebreaker.py", line 86, in <module>
print(del_symbol, "was not found")
NameError: name 'del_symbol' is not defined
```

If you take the time to read it, you will find that the last line says

```
NameError: name 'del_symbol' is not defined
```

This means exactly what is says. The variable `del_symbol` had not been created when the line `print(del_symbol, "was not found")` was run.

This is because you create the variable `del_symbol` inside the `if` section of your code:

```
if del_letter in words:
    del_symbol = dict.get(dictionary)
else:
    print(del_symbol, "was not found")
```

Notice that `del_symbol` is only ever created `if del_letter in words` is true. If this condition is not true, the program skips straight to `else`, and tries to run the `print` command. Then it realised that `del_symbol` has not been created, and prints the error.

I think what you meant was `print(del_letter, "was not found")`. This will work, because `del_letter` is created outside the `if` statemnt.

Also, I don't think that `del_symbol = dict.get(dictionary)` does what you think it does. You have to specify the symbol you are interested in like this:

```
del_symbol = dict.get(dictionary, del_letter)
```

Remember that when you create a dictionary, a new dictionary object is created, with all the same methods as the dictionary class, so you can do the same thing as above more easily as follows:

```
del_symbol = dictionary.get(del_letter)
```

Or even more simply:

```
del_symbol = dictionary[del_letter]
```

The only advantage of `dictionary.get()` over `dictionary[]` is that `dictionary.get()` allows you to pass default arguments if the key you are looking for is not found in the dictionary. e.g. If you want `del_symbol` to be the substitution if it can be found, or just `del_letter` if it can't be found, use the following:

```
del_symbol = dictionary.get(del_letter, del_letter)
```

`dictionary.get('letter', 'default_letter')`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to undo the pairing, remove the key from the dictionary. The dictionary will then only show the available pairings.

`.get()` takes an optional third argument, which is the value to be returned if the key is not found. It will return `None` by default.  You can use this to return the key (letter) if there is no match.

Here is a simplified example:

```
>>> pairs = dict()
>>> pairs['a'] = 'z'
>>> pairs['b'] = '4'
>>> pairs['c'] = 'r'
>>> for k,v in pairs.items():
...    print('Key: {0} Replacement: {1}'.format(k,v))
...
Key: a Replacement: z
Key: c Replacement: r
Key: b Replacement: 4
>>> sentence = 'A cat in the hat'
>>> ''.join(pairs.get(letter, letter) for letter in sentence)
'A rzt in the hzt'
>>> del(pairs['c'])
>>> pairs['t'] = 'o'
>>> ''.join(pairs.get(letter, letter) for letter in sentence)
'A czo in ohe hzo'
>>> for k,v in pairs.items():
...     print('Key: {0} Replacement: {1}'.format(k, v))
...
Key: a Replacement: z
Key: b Replacement: 4
Key: t Replacement: o
```

Now, for the user to be able to delete a key (pairing) from the dictionary, just ask them for the letter to be replaced and delete it (with `del()`).

This way your dictionary only contains the valid key pairs (replacements).

Comment: Note that the question is tagged with `python-3.x`, so `iteritems` won't work. For Python 3, `iteritems` should be replaced with just `items`.